# My supervisor does not have time to read my thesis, what do I do?

Tags: thesis, supervision, defense

I am a master's student, I started my degree in 2018. I wrote my thesis and sent it to both my main supervisor and co-supervisor a month ago and ask them to read but my main prof did not have time to read it. My co-supervisor reviewed it and he sent his feedbacks privately without including the main supervisor (it felt weird to me).

I emailed my main supervisor a few times and asked him to read it, and when he noticed that the co-supervisor is giving me feedbacks privately, he got annoyed. He (the main supervisor) then said that I can go for defense with my co-supervisor's revisions, and he does not have any revisions. He still does not want to read it.

I have a tight deadline to submit the final version. However, I would like to have his feedback, since he is my supervisor and knows my work more than my co-supervisor.

How do I get him to read the draft? Is it not rude to not consider his feedback?
What should I do in this situation?

Comment: How much power/control does the primary advisor have over your completion? Does he need to sign it, for example? It may be more important to know whether he has any objections to it, rather than giving feedback.

Comment: How do you mean by objection? He does not say I should not be graduated.

Answer (score 2):

**If there are places you feel need improvement ask about those only.  Ask your advisor if you're ready to defend.**

Make the changes suggested by the co-advisor, then ask your advisor about specific areas.  Finally, ask both advisors if you're ready to defend.  Hopefully this will make your current advisor realize where you are in the process, and maybe get you some attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is for this thesis to fulfill graduation requirements. Although having your supervisor read the thesis is probably helpful to this goal, it is not necessary for graduation. Ask if your advisor has any objections to it before you schedule your defense.

You can't force your advisor to read the thesis, but scheduling the defense is usually done by the student if the advisor doesn't object. It is the advisor's job to prepare students for their defense, and it's an awkward situation for the advisor if an unprepared student attempts to defend. If your advisor will approve your thesis for graduation, then it may not be necessary to convince your advisor to read it.